# What does the following x86 MOV instruction do?

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

Opcode with argument: `8B55 08`
Disassembled: `MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]`

Does this move the value *at* address `EBP+8` and place it into `EDX`? What does the `DWORD PTR` mean?

What's the easiest way to test x86 instructions? Is there a way for me to define all my registers and flags and then execute/test instructions like this easily?

I'm using the following manual, but it's quite difficult to read at first: http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The `DWORD PTR` specifies that the operand is 32 bits. It's is called a size directive and is explained further in [x86 Assembly Guide](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html)

You will be forced to use this kind of modifier when the assembler cannot tell the actual size of the operand.

The instruction in question moves a 32 bit value from the stack segment (SS) into `EDX`

Like pointed out by [@harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold) and [@brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559737/brendan) the default segment when using `EBP` as base address is `SS`, so in your case you should be able to use `mov edx, [ebp + 8]`

One way to test instructions like the above would be to use [inline assembler in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and make use of the [registers window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62680774.aspx) in which you will be able to edit and display different register values.

Comment: `ss` is the default segment when `ebp` is the base address, by the way

Comment: The original assembly probably would've been `mov edx,[ebp+8]` - there is no (unnecessary) SS override in the opcode, and the assembler should know that `EDX` is 32-bit without the `DWORD PTR` part. I'd assume that the disassembler added these things for completeness.